# How do I create glass panels in SwiftUI without using the Material Structure

Tags: css, ios, swift, swiftui

I want to make a glass panel like this.
https://codepen.io/kanishkkunal/pen/QWGzBwz

Here is the CSS for what I want to recreate

```css
.glass-panel {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 40px auto;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.06);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 32px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

Here's a tweet I posted earlier with the code I was working on
https://twitter.com/DevlanderJS/status/1644059601409826816

This is the code I currently have for my card, and I have tried to use  combinations of the blur modifier and overlay modifier to blur what's underneath it with no luck.

```swift
struct GlassContainer:  View {
    var height: Double
    
    var computedHeight: Double {
        return height
    }
    var body:  some View {
        
        ZStack{
            VStack{
                Color(
                    red: 255/255,
                    green: 255/255,
                    blue: 255/255,
                    opacity: 0.06)                
            }
            .frame(height: height)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))
            .border(
                Color(
                    red: 255/255,
                    green: 255/255,
                    blue: 255/255,
                    opacity: 0.1
                )
            ).cornerRadius(15)
        }
    }
}
```

I may be approaching this wrong. Could anyone give me some examples?
I don't want to use .ultraThinMaterial .regularThickMaterial, or any of the materials because I want to have my custom color, but I also want to have everything under my card blurred.

This is what I have now

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Here is a view with sliders where you can vary the opacity of the color and material.

You can use `Material` as you want. I never said you are required to make the `Material` less opaque, only that you could. Also, `Material` itself comes with different levels of blur from `.ultraThin` to `.ultraThick`. What you use is your choice. I am simply showing you how you can use it.

Sometimes it is better to see it in action:

```
struct GlassContainer: View {
    
    @State var colorOpacity = 0.5
    @State var materialOpacity = 0.5
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                ZStack {
                    Text("Some text underneath")
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .font(.title3)
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(
                            Material.thin
                        )
                        .opacity(materialOpacity)
                    Color(
                        red: 255/255,
                        green: 255/255,
                        blue: 255/255,
                        opacity: colorOpacity)
                }
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))
                .border(
                    Color(
                        red: 255/255,
                        green: 255/255,
                        blue: 255/255,
                        opacity: 0.1
                    )
                )
                .cornerRadius(15)
                    .frame(height: 300)
                Spacer()
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Text("Material Opacity:")
                    Slider(value: $materialOpacity)
                }
                .padding()

                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Text("Color Opacity:")
                    Slider(value: $colorOpacity)
                }
                .padding()
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct GlassContainer_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GlassContainer()
    }
}
```

Original answer:
You are missing the point of `Material`. It is meant to be layered:

```
struct GlassContainer:  View {
    var height: Double
    
    var computedHeight: Double {
        return height
    }
    var body:  some View {
        
        ZStack{
            VStack{
                Color(
                    red: 255/255,
                    green: 255/255,
                    blue: 255/255,
                    opacity: 0.06) 
                    .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
                    // Place the Material in a background to layer it. You will
                    // get your color and the glassy look. You can even set
                    // opacity on the Material to make in more transparent.
               
            }
            .frame(height: height)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))
            .border(
                Color(
                    red: 255/255,
                    green: 255/255,
                    blue: 255/255,
                    opacity: 0.1
                )
            ).cornerRadius(15)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so this doesn't fix my problem

Comment: I need the blur from the material effect. Nothing else, lowering the opacity is going to lower the blur.

Comment: `Material` is a mix and match view. You can pretty much use it how you wish. See my updated answer.

Comment: So I understand that. I need the blur amount to be 100% and the material part to be 0%. I am not getting the desired result I am trying to achieve. I don't think it can be done with the material. Wouldn't there be a way to do it with .blur and .overlay?

Comment: Do you have an image of what you are trying to achieve?